# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithPreDexForRelease'. > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException

Tags: android, exception, xmlbeans

I tried to build for making a APK using Generate Signed APK.
But I have some error..

```
Error:Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lorg/apache/xmlbeans/xml/stream/XMLName;
Error:Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lorg/apache/xmlbeans/xml/stream/XMLStreamException;
Error:Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lorg/apache/xmlbeans/xml/stream/utils/NestedThrowable;
Error:Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lorg/apache/xmlbeans/xml/stream/utils/NestedThrowable$Util;
Error:8 errors; aborting
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithPreDexForRelease'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to pre-dex 'C:\Users\AndroidStudioProjects\A\app\libs\xmlbeans-2.6.0.jar' to 'C:\Users\AndroidStudioProjects\A\app\build\intermediates\transforms\preDex\release\8'
```

And This is my Gradle file. And I don't know what is problem.. because it works well. Just I have a problem for making a APK.

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.android.A"
        multiDexEnabled true
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            lintOptions{
                checkReleaseBuilds false
                abortOnError false
            }
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'

    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:10.0.1'
    compile('org.apache.tika:tika-parsers:1.14'){
        exclude group: 'org.apache.xmlbeans'
    }
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.0.1'
    compile files('libs/curvesapi-1.04.jar')
    compile files('libs/poi-3.17.jar')
    compile files('libs/poi-examples-3.17.jar')
    compile files('libs/poi-excelant-3.17.jar')
    compile files('libs/poi-ooxml-3.17.jar')
    compile files('libs/poi-scratchpad-3.17.jar')
    compile files('libs/xmlbeans-2.6.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/poi-ooxml-schemas-3.17.jar')
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

How can I solve it? Help me please.

Comment: MultiDex might be the solution

Answer (score 0):

set default embedded JDK in your android studio like below and retry with clean build.

Select File -> Project structure -> Use embedded JDK(recommended)

If it won't resolve the issue increase the heap size and try again

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because you include the library in libs directory twice. First with:

```
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
```

Second with:

```
compile files('libs/curvesapi-1.04.jar')
compile files('libs/poi-3.17.jar')
compile files('libs/poi-examples-3.17.jar')
compile files('libs/poi-excelant-3.17.jar')
compile files('libs/poi-ooxml-3.17.jar')
compile files('libs/poi-scratchpad-3.17.jar')
compile files('libs/xmlbeans-2.6.0.jar')
compile files('libs/poi-ooxml-schemas-3.17.jar')
```

You only need to use the following line to include all the jar in your libs directory:

```
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
```